# Password Protect Virtual Directory With .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, virtual-directory, password-protected

I have a site with a virtual directory structure like `mysite.com/folder/title` which is actually a .htaccess rewrite to `mysite.com/f/index.php?p=title`. I want to password protect the folder `folder` with .htaccess, and know how to do that with actual folders. But I don't want to password protect the main site `mysite.com`, and right now if I put the .htaccess file in the `mysite.com` directory, I am protecting `mysite.com` and `mysite.com/folder`. I have also tried protecting `mysite.com/f`.

How can I protect only `mysite.com/folder` using .htaccess?

.htaccess contents of `mysite.com`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /f/index.php?p=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^folder/*$ /f/index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

.htaccess file I tried in `mysite.com/f` This successfully protects the entire site when moved into the other .htaccess file, so I know the path is correct.

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /home/myusername/.htpasswd
```

Comment: I just plugged your question title into Google and found many articles that answer it far better than I ever could.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've also done that and read those articles. Unfortunately, none of those answer the question, and the only question that asks the same thing as me is left unanswered. If you have found the answer, could you possibly post the link here?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't be putting that configuration (the rewrite rules) in .htaccess files, you should be putting it in the main configuration file under a Directory section (assuming you have access to that file). The [Apache docs explain why](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#when).

You should check that you have the correct AllowOverride settings. If it's all setup correctly, having the .htaccess file you specified sitting in the mysite/f folder should be enough to password protect it.

Comment: I would but I don't have access to those files. Do you know if there is a workaround just using .htaccess?